# Ignore Blank Cells Within IF statement That is Using "And"

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the below script to search through 4 cell values. It deletes all the rows that contain all values above 10. However, I am struggling with adding a nested "IF" statement to ignore blanks.

```
Sub test()

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "D").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "E").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "F").Value2 >= 10 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to avoid delete if **any** cell in *C* through *F* is empty??

Comment: Well lets say one column says 20 and the other 3 are empty, I want it to delete the row.

Comment: And what happens if `C2` is 20, `D2` is blank and `E2` is 5?

Comment: it leaves it cinse E2 is below 10. I figured that the easiest way is to go to the empty cells and turn them into 99 (any number higher than 10 really) . That way if the other cells that do contain values and are higher than 10 will get deleted. After running that, it goes and replaces the 99 back to empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub test()

```
Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "", "999", xlWhole

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "D").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "E").Value2 >= 10 And Cells(i, "F").Value2 >= 10 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "999", "", xlWhole


End Sub
```